# Dynamic fields validation in Yup (Formik)

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have a number of select fields generated based on the API request, I am trying to validate those **Formik** select fields through **Yup** **validationSchema**.

**Validation Schema**

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
            ...other fields...,
            privilege_levels: Yup.lazy(obj =>
                Yup.object(
                  mapValues(obj, (value, key) => {
                        return Yup.number().required('Required');
                  })
                )
            ),
```

**Fields** that have to be validated

```
{funds_permissions_enabled &&   
            <fieldset className="formikFieldset">
                <legend className="formikLegend">Permission Levels</legend>
                { funds && funds.results.map(fund => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <label className="required" htmlFor={`id_privilege_level_` + fund.id}>
                            Permission level for {fund.name}
                            </label>
                            <select
                                name="privilege_levels"
                                // name={`privilege_level_` + fund.id}
                                id={`id_privilege_level_` + fund.id}
                                className="select"
                                // onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            >
                                <option key="" value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Permission Level</option>
                                { levels && levels.map((option) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={option[0]} value={option[0]}>
                                        { option[1] }
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                }) }
                          </select>
                        { formik.errors.privilege_levels && props.formSubmitted ? <div className="formikError">{formik.errors.privilege_levels}</div> : null }
                        </div>
                    )
                }) }
            </fieldset>}
```

**onSubmit function**

```
onSubmit: async (values, validate )=> {
 if (funds_permissions_enabled) {
                let privilege_levels = funds.results.reduce((ac,fund) => ({...ac,[''+fund.id]: parseInt( document.getElementById('id_privilege_level_'+fund.id).value) }), {});
                values['privilege_levels'] = privilege_levels;
                validate(values['privilege_levels']) <--- is not working
            }
```

The final object after reduce function looks like this, `<id>: <fund_id>` - `{1: 30, 2: 20, 3: 34, 4: 78, 5: 90}`. I need to check that the `<fund_id>` is not `NaN` and is selected for every select field.

I've also disabled onBlur and onChange validation in useFormik to make sure the `privilege_levels` are being validated only after they are converted to the right format

```
validateOnChange: false, 
validateOnBlur: false,
```

I'm stuck with this one for a while, any help is highly appreciated, thanks!